# how to use output how to use output url from one test as input url to another test

Tags: eclipse, selenium, junit4

I research now Selenium with eclipse and use junit tests. How to use output  url from one test case as input url to another test case

Answer (score 0):

If the tests were written in a single class use a global variable. If they were executing under a Single JVM instance , but different classes use a Environment variable

Comment: Thanks Harsha, you helped me a lot.